# Powershell warning and error handling

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-file, warnings

The following code I am writing to replace a batch script which I have below.

```bsh
$Script:srcpath = ((Get-Location).Path)
$Script:configure = "$Script:srcpath\qtbase\configure.bat"

if (Get-Item "$Script:srcpath\qtbase\configure.bat" -WarningAction (Write-Warning "$Script:configure not found. Did you forget to run 'init-repository'?")) {
    continue
}
```

I am try to rewrite the qt configure batch script:

```batch
set "srcpath=%~dp0"
set "configure=%srcpath%qtbase\configure.bat"
if not exist "%configure%" (
    echo %configure% not found. Did you forget to run "init-repository"? >&2
    exit /b 1
)

if not exist qtbase mkdir qtbase || exit /b 1

echo + cd qtbase
cd qtbase || exit /b 1

echo + %configure% -top-level %*
call %configure% -top-level %*
set err=%errorlevel%

cd ..

exit /b %err%
```

The error I am getting in PowerShell is the following:

```
Get-Item : Cannot bind parameter 'WarningAction' to the target. Exception setting
"WarningAction": "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."
At line:4 char:67
+ ... rningAction (Write-Warning "$Script:configure not found. Did you forg ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : WriteError: (:) [Get-Item], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterBindingFailed,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetItemCommand
```

The problem is the error being thrown is erroneous because the warning am calling is what should take its place to tell people that the item doesn't exist. so run "init-repository".

There isn't a good, "if not exist" in PowerShell.

Okay, there is, but it looks like this:

```
catch [System.Management.Automation.ItemNotFoundException]
```

which I am having problems with getting to work.

Why am I  doing this before someone asks is because I feel that Microsoft will phase out CMD some time it's good to have updated scripts.

Comment: You can use `Test-Path` to see if a file exists: `if (-not (Test-Path -path $whatever)) { Write-Warning 'Does not exist!' }'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Why it's not working**

`WarningAction` does not work like that.

From the [about_CommonParameters documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_commonparameters?view=powershell-5.1):

> Determines how the cmdlet responds to a warning from the command. "Continue" is the default value. This parameter works only when the command generates a warning message. For example, this parameter works when a command contains the Write-Warning cmdlet.

So, essentially, the value of `WarningAction` is `Continue` by default and can be set to `Inquire`, `SilentlyContinue` or `Stop`. The value it is set to determine what action is taken *if* the `Get-item` command throws a warning, not what warning to write if `Get-item` throws a warning.

You can change the [preference variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_preference_variables?view=powershell-7.3#warningpreference) `$WarningPreference` to set the `WarningAction` within the current scope, or precede by a scope modifier.

---

**How to make it work**

**`Test-Path`**

I second [Richard's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45955561/powershell-warning-and-error-handling?noredirect=1#comment78869009_45955561) to use `Test-Path`. This will return `True` or `False`, depending on whether it finds the file.

```
if (-not (Test-Path -Path "$Script:srcpath\qtbase\configure.bat")){
    Write-Warning 'Does not exist!'
    # do other stuff
    continue
}else{
    Get-Item $configure
}
```

**`try`/`catch`**

You could try to catch the exception thrown by `Get-Item` directly in a [try/catch](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_try_catch_finally?view=powershell-5.1). In a similar way to `WarningAction`, there is `ErrorAction` which determines what to do if an error is thrown. Terminating error is required, so `ErrorAction` is set to `Stop`.

```
try{
    Get-Item $configure -ErrorAction Stop
}catch [System.Management.Automation.ItemNotFoundException]{
    Write-Output "Item not found"
    # do other stuff
}catch{
    Write-Output "Some other error"
    $Error[0] # prints last error
}
```

Comment: Thank you. That solved my problem. Do you know a good resource for learning how to write for Powershell?

Comment: [This](https://www.manning.com/books/learn-windows-powershell-in-a-month-of-lunches-third-edition) is generally recommended. My exp: 1st half + some of the later chapters useful, but focused too much on Windows Admin for me. Key thing it taught me and I want to stress: **learn to use built-in help and RTFM**. It's invaluable. Quick google leads to [this](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2015/01/04/weekend-scripter-the-best-ways-to-learn-powershell/) and [this](http://whatpixel.com/10-best-powershell-books/) - read, see which most fits your needs and learning style.